# c# LastIndexOf with few words

Tags: string, whitespace, lastindexof

I'm trying to get LAST index of "hello world" in text string.

```cs
            string sourceText = "hello world. no yes what where hello world but not right in left hello world end of text";
            string searchIndex = "hello world";
            int index = sourceText.LastIndexOf(searchIndex);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                Console.Write(index);
            }
```

but it's always returns -1.

Comment: Just tried your code. Everything is fine for me - index is equal to 65.

Comment: yeah,it's fine for me too....index is 65

Comment: Your code is correct.I copy the same code and executed it gives the index as 65.
Just check your Program once again...

Comment: Strange, maybe my code does not work because the text in Russian?

Comment: everybody.
I found a problem.
There in the text there is a tabulation character